# How to pass variable to modal?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

How to pass value to hidden div?

I have the following code:

I have tried many different combinations from the internet, however, I am extremely thick in applying sample code into practice - I am the type of person who needs to see it being done to comprehend. I am just a novice and to be honest, I am really happy with the results even though most of the time I spend experimenting with code.

Essentially what I want to achieve is that I will pass the correct value of report_id to associate it with data from the database and apply some logic to it.
However ID doesn't appear in div, well it actually does but only the first one, I have tried to use foreach() but without success. What I want to achieve is that I have a list of open actions and I can just press the button, hidden div (modal) appears, apply some values and away it goes to the controller.

Thank you.

Ps. Thats all in the same file.

```
Modal

<div role="dialog" id="dialog1" aria-labelledby="dialog1_label" aria-modal="true" class="hidden">
     <center><h2 class="govuk-heading-m">Actions:</h2></center>
     <fieldset class="govuk-fieldset">
     <div class="govuk-form-group">
     <form id="MY_post" method="post" for="report_id" action="<?= base_url() ?>/admin/actionReportedPost">
     
     <input type="hidden" name="report_id" value="<?php //echo $row->report_id ?>">

     <fieldset class="govuk-fieldset">
     <legend class="govuk-fieldset__legend govuk-fieldset__legend--l">
      <h1 class="govuk-fieldset__heading">
      Ban poster?
      <?php //echo $row->report_id ?>
      </h1>
    </legend>
    <label class="govuk-label" for="sort">
    Select action:
    </label>
     <select class="govuk-select" id="board_id" for="board_id">
            <option value="null">Do nothing</option>
            <option value="day">Ban for one day</option>
            <option value="week">Ban for one week</option>
            <option value="month">Ban for one month</option>
            <option value="permanent">Permanent</option>
    </select>
    <legend class="govuk-fieldset__legend govuk-fieldset__legend--l">
      <h1 class="govuk-fieldset__heading">
      Delete post?
      </h1>
    </legend>
    <div class="govuk-radios">
      <div class="govuk-radios__item">
        <input class="govuk-radios__input" id="action" name="action" type="radio" value="y">
        <label class="govuk-label govuk-radios__label" for="action">
          Yes
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="govuk-radios__item">
        <input class="govuk-radios__input" id="action" name="action" type="radio" value="n">
        <label class="govuk-label govuk-radios__label" for="action">
          No
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  </div>
  <span style="float:right;">
    <button class="govuk-button govuk-button--warning" data-module="govuk-button">
      Take action
    </button>
</form>
</span>
  <span style="float:left;">
  <form method="post" action="<?= base_url() ?>/admin/reportedposts">
    <button class="govuk-button govuk-button--secondary" data-module="govuk-button">
      Return back
    </button>
</form>
</span>

</div>
```

```
Rest of the page
<table class="govuk-table">
  <thead class="govuk-table__head">
    <tr class="govuk-table__row">
      <th scope="col" class="govuk-table__header govuk-table__header">Report ID</th>
      <th scope="col" class="govuk-table__header govuk-table__header">Post ID</th>
      <th scope="col" class="govuk-table__header govuk-table__header--numeric">Created At</th>
      <th scope="col" class="govuk-table__header govuk-table__header--numeric">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="govuk-table__body"> 
    <?php foreach($reported_posts as $row){ ?>
    <tr class="govuk-table__row">
      <th scope="row" class="govuk-table__header"><?php echo $row->report_id ?></th>
      <td class="govuk-table__cell"><?php echo $row->post_id ?></td>
      <td class="govuk-table__cell"><?php echo $row->sub_post_id ?></td>
      <td class="govuk-table__cell"><?php echo $row->created_at ?></td>
      <form method='post' id="post_id" name="post_id"><td class="govuk-table__cell"><button formaction="<?= base_url(); ?>/board/subPost?post_id=<?= $row->post_id ?>" class="govuk-button govuk-button--secondary" data-module="govuk-button">Go to post</button></td></form>
      <td><form method='post' id="report_id" name="report_id" onsubmit="return false"><input type="button" name="report_id" value="<?php echo $row->post_id ?>" onclick="openDialog('dialog1', this)" class="govuk-button govuk-button--warning" data-module="govuk-button">
    </td></form>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: HI Karol, could you please reduce all this code to just the essential to reproduce your problem! see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). thank you

Comment: also see CI documentation on [CI 4.x how to pass a variable to the view](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html#display-the-news) and [CI 3.x how to pass a variable to the view](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/news_section.html#display-the-news)

Comment: Vickel, data is being passed to the view so problem isn't there. Every row has buttons with actions, and one of these opens modal, however modal does not contain the right value which is report_id

Comment: well, please see my 1st comment and present a MRE

Comment: probably a typo: `value="<?php echo $row->post_id ?>"` in the 2nd form most likely should say `value="<?php echo $row->report_id?>"`? just a guess...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.